# Почему так долго открывается url selenium

Tags: python, авторизация

Учусь авторизоваться. Браузер открывается сразу, но очень долго, может даже секунд 10 висит в адресной строке data:, - почему так происходит, что не сразу открывается браузер с нужным мне адресом?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

chrome_options = Options()
driver1 = Service("./chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?mode=auth&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fwebmaster.yandex.ru%2Fsites%2F"

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: а time.sleep(5) там для чего написано?

Comment: time.sleep(5) это фриз окна после прогрузки url в браузере, а у меня url подставляется в браузерную строку за 10 сек, а до этого в браузере висит data:,

Comment: Проблема не с селениумом, а с интернетом. Лично у меня если через домашний интернет запускать, то грузиться за секунду-две. Если через мобильный, то как у Вас

Comment: Да, действительно оказалось, что проблема была с интернетом.